# how to train pytorch cnn model with 110k images on google colab?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a pytorch cnn with 110k+ images of shape (2,128,128). My data is in a h5 file. If I pass the input using a dataset class with init, getitem and len, one epoch takes about 3hrs, which I cannot afford. If i try to extract all the data beforehand, my google colab runs out of RAM. What can I do to reduce training time?

Comment: Have you tried extracting data in Google Drive and mounting the drive to colab?

Comment: The.h5 files are uploaded to my Google Drive